# is crontab broken on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, cron

**Question.** Is `cron` supposed to work in OSX El Capitan?

**Background.** I've used crontab for years on OSX, but with El Capitan it seems not to work. I added my username to `/usr/lib/cron/cron.allow` and even rebooted the machine, but still my cron jobs don't do anything, nor do they mail me with errors. The manpages suggest Apple doesn't want people using cron, but they don't say it is nonfunctional (yet).

Comment: What are the permissions and owner/group settings for your cron.allow?

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  7 24 Sep 08:11 /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow

Comment: yep that's correct. I can't imagine Apple would disable it, well, maybe I can :p

Comment: It seems to be working normally for me under the current beta (and perms on /usr/lib/cron/cron.allow are the same). There's still a launch daemon to fire it off if /etc/crontab or /usr/lib/cron//tabs/* exist.

Comment: Yes, this is odd. I see that /usr/sbin/cron is running (as root), so the system has noticed that a user is hoping to get cron activity. I'll keep playing with this and report back if I find a solution. I really do prefer cron to launchd because I want to be able to share code with colleagues who are not on osx.

Comment: It's working fine for me (original reporter) now, with OSX 10.11.6 beta. I don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems to work for me, but I think you need to specify the editor:

`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`

Add your crons, and then save the file with the name and location given. In my case it's a file in `/tmp/crontab.xxxx`.

Then if you do `crontab -l` you should see your crons.

Comment: Thanks. It is a little confusing confusing because the file starts off blank in OSX. Normally in linux there is some help text up the top.

Comment: Thanks @jesús-carrera for finding this, I was very disappointed about cron dysfunction... but does know WHY Apple would change something like this?! Terrible. geezer mentions at and batch are sometimes grouped together with cron but no one has ever mentioned them before

Answer (score 17):

This is another answer for anyone that finds this via Google. There aren't many results.

For me, somehow `/usr/lib/cron` was symlinked to `/var/at` (which I'd never even heard of…), and `/var/at` had a `cron.allow` file, which my username wasn't in, so running `sudo vi /var/at/cron.allow` and adding my username (somehow redirecting `echo` into that file didn't work…) fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I was trying to get 'at' working and through this answer I eventually figured out that 'atrun' was disabled by default.  See `man atrun` for details on enabling it.

Comment: Worked for High Sierra (10.13.2), as well

Answer (score 12):

For Mojave, **Full Disk Access** prevents you from changing system files (which includes privacy related data as well as system configuration like the crontabs).

To enable access:

- Go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**
- press the + button
- Add your terminal app (eg /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app or /Applications/iTerm.app)
- Restart your terminal app
- Configure cron
- Optional, but highly recommended: Remove your terminal app from **Full Disk Access** when done

Comment: For Mojave ,user rights management is getting stricter. You save my time

Comment: I have given both cron, Terminal.app full disk access in Mojave. Still not working. Any other reason why cron is still not running?

Answer (score 8):

On a MacBook, using El Capitan (10.11.5), "cron" still works just fine.

"/usr/lib/cron.deny" is the default (lists "Guest" only), and there is no "cron.allow".  Don't recall doing any customisations to make it work (no init/config files mods, no chmod's, no file/dir creates/deletes, etc.).

(Was using 10.6.* until that MacBook died in April.  Began using 10.11 in mid-May, restored my crontab after the 10.11.5 update (?late May?).  So don't know if cron was working under 10.11, or re-enabled by the 10.11.5 update.)

Try this simple test: "crontab -e", then "*/5 * * * * date >> /tmp/z.date".  Should see a new date every five minutes.

If that works, try "*/5 * * * * env >> /tmp/z.date.1", and check your environment.  E.g., the default PATH is quite short.

Btw, "at" is a batch job queue.  "at", "batch", and "cron" are often grouped together, as they do variations of the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you type `cd /usr/lib/cron` then `ls` you'll see you have `at.deny` and `cron.deny`, but no `at.allow` or `cron.allow`.

Run `sudo nano cron.allow` and enter your usernames one per line.

Create a copy for `at.allow` as such `sudo cp cron.allow at.allow`.

I created those two file and it started running.

Answer (score 4):

cron will completely skip any jobs while the machine is asleep. Try checking your energy saver settings (see below).

launchd (Apple's recommended alternative) also doesn't run while the machine is asleep, but won't skip jobs. Instead the jobs run when the machine awakens.

[image: Energy Saver Settings]

Comment: The problem with this is that I need my job to run only when my machine is awake and to not run when I wake it if it has been skipped while my machine is asleep. I have been unable to find a reliable way of making this work with launchd.

Comment: @pheon - That's a different problem from OP, so my answer here to disable sleep doesn't apply. In your case, a regular cron job using crontab should do what you want, since cron jobs are skipped on OS X when the computer is asleep.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, cron was deprecated a while back.  They must have finally pulled the plug in the GM of El Capitan.  Apple suggests using launchd instead of cron.  Here's a tutorial:
[launchd](http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs)

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. It may be detestable but this IS what Apple wants you to do