# Is 'at' broken in OSX?

Tags: macos, cron, launchd

'at' is a UNIX/BSD/Linux programming tool I use in scheduling some operational forecasting models.  In testing some of my scripts on my Mac laptop, I found that the `at` tool accepted job submissions without error, and reported them in queue, but ultimately did not execute them.

Searching for useful answers for the `at` tool is difficult because of the common-as-dirt name. However, I saw [is crontab broken on OSX El Capitan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781884/is-crontab-broken-on-osx-el-capitan) while trying to solve this problem.

```
$ at now + one minute
echo "hello world" |say
^D
$ atq  # list at jobs...
7   Mon Mar 13 14:31:00 2017
$
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the steps in BOTH of the answers below are necessary. Better yet, just follow the link in @DavidSewell's answer for a response that's both complete and up-to-date, as of macOS 12.2.1 (Monterey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but it is disabled by default.  See `man at` and `man atrun` for details.  Darwin based systems use `launchd` rather than `init` to invoke programs like `crond` and `atrun`.

Start `atrun` with

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Or enable it for future bootups by modifying `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist` to have:

```
...
<key>Enabled</key>
...
```

Comment: Note that on recent versions of macOS, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist` is located in the read-only part of the system and you cannot modify it withotu disabling SIP.

Answer (score 5):

On Mojave, it is also necessary to add /usr/libexec/atrun to the Full Disk Access list in OS X's Security and Privacy settings. See discussion and instructions here: [Making “at” work on macOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840/335344)